# Getting the sorted sequence from a level-wise sorted min-heap

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, sorting, heaps

[image]
A *heap sorted by levels* is a heap which:

1. Every parent is smaller than its children.
2. The nodes in each level are sorted from the smallest to the greatest.

I need to describe an algorithm with $O(n)$ runtime that prints the values in the heap in sorted order.

I only manage to do it in $O(n \log(\log n))$ using another heap but  have no idea of how to do it in $O(n)$.

Comment: Is it **1.** means that parent with value $P$ can have child with value $C$ such that $P > C$ (i.e. parent is bigger that child)?

Comment: 1. What does "smaller than is 1/2 children's" mean?  Can you edit to rephrase that sentence?  2. What have you tried?  What approaches have you considered?  We discourage bare problem statements that just ask us to solve your exercise/problem for you.  3. Please edit to improve the title.

Comment: I think "1/2 children" meant "all of the children, of which there may be one or two". I edited thus. Is that what you wanted to state, Yoav? (cc @D.W.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a recursive algorithm.  Suppose the heap has depth $D$.  Recursively compute a sorted list of all the numbers in the top $D-1$ levels (i.e., all but the bottom level); let $L$ be this list.  Let $L'$ be the list of numbers in the bottom level.  Note that both $L$ and $L'$ are in sorted order, so we can use the Merge procedure from Mergesort to compute a sorted list of all of the numbers.

If you work out the recurrence relation, you'll see that the running time of this algorithm is $O(n)$.  Indeed, Merge runs in $cn$ time, for some constant $c$, so the total running time will be $cn + cn/2 + cn/4 + \dots \le 2cn = O(n)$.